# Reading and saving post data

Tags: c#, post, listener, file-transfer

I have been assigned to take over someones position, however I do not really know C#. There is a server (192.268. something ect) that will post data to a site (unknown site, lets say bleh.com)

This is what the posting code snippet looks like:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
  "https://server-ip-here/postlistener?filename=filename.zlib");

req.UseNagleAlgorithm = true;
req.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
req.Method = "POST";
req.Accept = "application/xml";
req.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
System.Net.ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = false;
req.Proxy = new WebProxy();

filename = "filename.dat";
byte[] postData = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
stream.Flush();
stream.Close();

req.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(responseHandler), this);
```

Which I beleive I get the post request in this form

> www.blah.com/upload?filename=file_1234_12389126495129847980.zlib

I am unsure how to listen for post requests and then get the data from them and save them as a file.

Currently I have tried this:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     listener = new HttpListener();
     // listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:8000/");
     listener.Prefixes.Add("http://127.0.0.1:8000/");

     listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous;

     listener.Start();
     listenThread1 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(startlistener));
     listenThread1.Start();
 }

 private void startlistener(object s)
 {
     while (true)
     {               
         // blocks until a client has connected to the server
         ProcessRequest();
     }
 }

 private void ProcessRequest()
 {
     var result = listener.BeginGetContext(ListenerCallback, listener);
     result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
 }

 private void ListenerCallback(IAsyncResult result)
 {
     var context = listener.EndGetContext(result);
     Thread.Sleep(1000);

     var data_text = new StreamReader(
         context.Request.InputStream,
         context.Request.ContentEncoding).ReadToEnd();

     var cleaned_data = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(data_text);

     context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
     context.Response.StatusDescription = "OK";

     MessageBox.Show(cleaned_data);
     context.Response.Close();
 }
```

Which listens on the local host (Would sub local host for the website once we establish what it will be).

Not sure how to grab the post though, right now I can only listen for it. Ideally I would only like to accept posts from a specific IP address also.

Any ideas how I can go about grabbing the post data (which will be binary) and saving it as a file?

Comment: Ehm... are you sure you're creating the right project type? it seems more like an ASP .net project to me than a WinForms one... creating all the Http infrastructure is not a trivial work, and ASP + IIS gives all those things already done.

Comment: @Gusman I am not sure I am building it in the right project haha. I havn't done c# coding, I just took over for a coworker, got assigned this project for some reason... Didn't even know where to start, was just doing my best gueses

Comment: Hehehe, ok, then what you need is a WebAPI project or ASP project, it's the web counterpart of C#, it will handle all the POST parsing for you, but you need to know how it works, just look for some tutorials (as I see the client wants an XML response, it all smells a bit like it's expecting a SOAP service, just seek some tutorials for .net WebServices or WCF services).

Comment: @Gusman If I can already listen to for Posts being made to the local host like that, do I really need the WebAPI or ASP project to just grab the data? There isn't just some easy function to grab all the data? Also there is no easy function to get the URL of the post so I can figure out the file name?

Comment: well, you must then decode the POST'ed data, first of all, don't use an StreamReader to read the data as it will be binary (you're uplading a file), use a plain Stream and read the data in chunks until you got all the content, and to get the file name, you can use  context.Request.QueryString["filename"] as the client is passing the file name in the query string.

Comment: Also, if this is going to be hosted on a web server it will not allow you to deploy a desktop program, it will expect a web project of some type.